# Property token does not exist on type Object

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-role-based-authentication-with-passport-in-ionic-2-part-2/) but since I'm using a newer version of Angular and Ionic (Angular 5 and Ionic 3), I got errors on these lines below

```
this.token = data.token;
this.storage.set('token', data.token);
```

Visual Studio code display this error:
`Property token does not exist on type 'Object'`

The code for the function is as below:

```
createAccount(details){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post('https://YOUR_HEROKU_APP.herokuapp.com/api/auth/register', JSON.stringify(details), {headers: headers})
          .subscribe(res => {

            let data = res.json();
            this.token = data.token;
            this.storage.set('token', data.token);
            resolve(data);

          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });

    });

  }
```

What should I change in my code?

Comment: what does your json() function return? maybe you need to parse the text first with JSON.parse(res);

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try parsing it as,

```
  this.token = data['token'];
  this.storage.set('token', this.token);
```

Answer (score 2):

If Typescript not able to identify the property 'token' on your object 'res' change  to  res: any

```
this.http.post(api.url, params)
        .subscribe((res:any) => { 
...
..
}
```